# Checking whether a property value equals to a predefined one in a list of objects

Tags: c#, list, linq, class

I have two classes like this

```
public class Stock
{
    public StockItem Item;

    public string Location;

    public int Quantity;

    public string Price;
}

public class StockItem
{
    public string Code;

    public string Name;

    public string Unit;
}
```

And I have a list that contains multiple instances of the `Stock` class

```
var stockList = new List<Stock>();
```

I am trying to determine whether the `Name` property of each instance inside the list is equal to a predefined string. Currently, I am looping through the list like this

```
foreach (var stock in stockList)
{
    if (stock.Item.Name.ToLower() == "test")
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Found the class")

        break;                      
    }
}
```

However, I was wondering if there was a more efficient way to do this using Linq or something similar to the `.Contains` method. Is there a simpler or more efficient way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> whether the Name property of each instance inside the list is equal
>   to a predefined string

Not much more efficient but simpler:

```
bool allAreEqual = stockList.All(x => x.Item.Name.Equals("test", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
```

If you instead want to find the first which matches the condition(what your loop really does):

```
Stock si = stockList.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Item.Name.Equals("test", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
```

Now you know if such a `Stock` exists(`si != null`) at all and you got it.

Answer (score 0):

All in linq will return True or false

```
stockList.All(p => p.Item.Name.ToLower() == "test");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Linq `Any()` method:

```
bool containsItemName = stockList.Any(x => x.Item.Name.Equals("MyName", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase));
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you really looking at all instances? From your question, it seems as if `Any`might be the way to go, see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.any?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Linq_Enumerable_Any__1_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__System_Func___0_System_Boolean__).

`stockList.Any(p => p.Item.Name.ToLower() == "test");`

Answer (score 0):

You can get a result what you wanted by calling `Any`

```cs
bool result = stockList.Any(
    stock => stock.Item.Name.Equals("text", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)
);
```

In this code, the parameter name `stock` can be changed whatever you want.